# How can I get Xcode to remember my Git credentials?

Tags: xcode

Does anyone know how to get Xcode to remember Git credentials for a Git repository that is not hosted on Github or Bitbucket or Gitlab? My company uses Beanstalk.

Comment: Run `git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain` to save your git password in KeyChain. Xcode will ask for access to KeyChain and then use it whenever needed.

Comment: Don't treat Xcode as a substitute for a good Git client. It isn't one. Use the command line or Sourcetree.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but running that command did nothing useful on my computer.

Comment: For what it's worth -- the git command line client does remember my credentials. It's only Xcode that does not.